# Smartphone signal blocking

Tags: applications

I have a Faraday bag which stores credit cards as well as my smartphone. After 2 layers of Faraday fabric, phone calls and emails will be blocked, but not text messages, they get through. I would like to block ALL incoming messages/calls from my phone when stored inside the closed bag. Why do the text messages get through when at times the phone calls and emails do not?

Comment: Get a better Faraday bag

Comment: Reposted from Electronics.SE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/631096/57290 (closed). In case it's deleted, some of the comments from there may be relevant:

Comment: [mkeith commented](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/631096/smartphone-signal-blocking#comment1669246_631096), "*I don't know exactly but the basic idea is that it is easy to send texts (especially SMS as opposed to MMS) over a noisy, laggy, low-bandwidth channel because the information density is low, and it doesn't matter if the data transmission rate is slow. If it takes 60 seconds to transmit 1024 bytes, texts can get through. Internet connection, not so much.*"

Comment: [StarCat commented](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/631096/smartphone-signal-blocking#comment1669260_631096), "*Phone messages will be stored by the provider until your phone contacts the cellular network. Regular calls are only registered when your phone is actually connected at the time of the call. It seems your Faraday bag is not completely impenetrable for radio signals.*"

Comment: SMS is a GSM (you could call it 2G) the oldest part of cellular phone communication and thus the lowest and most robust regarding how the data is encoded on the wireless interface. Also the maximum sending power is AFIK the highest among all GSM standards which makes it the most difficult to block. Also the amount of data needed for an SMS is extreme small so if your faraday bag has a minor defect this might be enough to allow communication for a very short time and thus the SMS comes through.